# I have binded a grid with List<int> (temporary list), how can i pick the list text into controls text in item template in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have binded a grid with List (temporary list),
how can I pick the list text into controls text in item template in grid view.

**aspx**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDenomination" runat="server"> 
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value">
            <ItemTemplate> 
                <asp:Label ID="lblValue" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("lstdenomination") %>'> </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete"> 
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
stdenomination.Add(Convert.ToInt32(txtDenomination.Text));
gvDenomination.DataSource = lstdenomination;
gvDenomination.DataBind();
```

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="gvDenomination" runat="server">
<Columns><asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value"><ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblValue" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("lstdenomination") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
<ItemTemplate><asp:LinkButton runat="server">Delete</asp:LinkButton</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns></asp:GridView>

Comment: lstdenomination.Add(Convert.ToInt32(txtDenomination.Text));
gvDenomination.DataSource = lstdenomination;
gvDenomination.DataBind();

Comment: Please, if you want to provide extra information, don't use the comment section rather edit your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you, `lstdenomination` is a `List<int>`. You can do this

```
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value">
        <ItemTemplate> 
            <asp:Label ID="lblValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>'> </asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```